# Android Volley nad Genson Web Service

Tags: java, json, android-volley

I am trying to pull data from json webservist with Volley and Genson. But it does not give an error, but it does not pull data. The problem is here. Can anyone help me please.

```
private void GetData()
{
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
final String url = "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
new Response.Listener<String>()
{
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
// response
Log.d("Response", response);
ParseData(response);
}
},
new Response.ErrorListener()
{
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
// error
Log.d("Error.Response", error.getLocalizedMessage());
}
}
)
{
};
queue.add(postRequest);
}
private void ParseData(String data)
{
Genson genson = new Genson();
try {
Servis[] persons = genson.deserialize(data, Servis[].class);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
String hata = e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
}
public class Servis implements Serializable {
public String id;
public String name;
public String full_name;
}
```

Comment: it looks like yo aren't doing anything with the result... perhaps print the content of persons and the stacktrace in the catch block.

Comment: it comes up here.... StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, after go to queue.add(postRequest);  Why do that.

Comment: Can anyone help me please...

Comment: Help me please. Can anyone help me please.